# Trying to compile a ROS 2 Eloquent package depending on a pure cmake package using colcon

Tags: ros, ros2, cmake, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

I have been fighting for some time with CMakeLists trying to compile a ROS 2 Eloquent package (bar) depending on a pure cmake package (foo) using colcon but I get the following error:

```
<...>/bar.hpp:5:10: fatal error: foo/foo.hpp: No such file or directory  
 #include "foo/foo.hpp"
```

I've made a minimal repo showing my problem here: https://github.com/MarcTestier/ros2_cmake_test.

The install folder of the cmake package (foo) seems somewhat normal though, its folder tree looks like this:

```
install/foo/  
├── include  
│   └── foo  
│       ├── foo.hpp  
│       └── foo_export.h  
├── lib  
│   └── libfoo.so  
└── share  
    ├── colcon-core  
    │   └── packages  
    │       └── foo  
    └── foo  
        ├── cmake  
        │   ├── fooConfig.cmake  
        │   ├── fooConfigVersion.cmake  
        │   ├── fooTargets-noconfig.cmake  
        │   └── fooTargets.cmake  
        ├── hook  
        │   ├── cmake_prefix_path.dsv  
        │   ├── cmake_prefix_path.ps1  
        │   ├── cmake_prefix_path.sh  
        │   ├── ld_library_path_lib.dsv  
        │   ├── ld_library_path_lib.ps1  
        │   ├── ld_library_path_lib.sh  
        │   ├── pkg_config_path.dsv  
        │   ├── pkg_config_path.ps1  
        │   ├── pkg_config_path.sh  
        │   ├── pkg_config_path_multiarch.dsv  
        │   ├── pkg_config_path_multiarch.ps1  
        │   └── pkg_config_path_multiarch.sh  
        ├── package.bash  
        ├── package.dsv  
        ├── package.ps1  
        ├── package.sh  
        └── package.zsh
```

It seems like the ROS 2 package (bar) has trouble finding the cmake package (foo) library and headers but `find_package(foo)` works.

I found an ugly solution (available in the repo [here](https://github.com/MarcTestier/ros2_cmake_test/blob/master/bar/CMakeLists2.txt)) which consists of 2 steps:

1.Manually add the include directory

```
get_filename_component(INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX} DIRECTORY)
include_directories(${INSTALL_DIR}/foo/include/)
```

If I only perform step 1, I can find the header files but I get an error: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfoo` which I guess means that even though I do the following:

```
target_link_libraries(Bar foo)
```

Bar still can't properly find the foo library.

2.If on top of the first step I link directly against the .so file:

```
target_link_libraries(Bar "${INSTALL_DIR}/foo/lib/libfoo.so")
```

Now the packages can compile but the solution seems a bit ugly.

I'm out of idea and I can't tell if the problem comes from a pure cmake problem, colcon moving/linking stuff around or anything else so any suggestions are welcomed, thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344399/trying-to-compile-a-ros-2-eloquent-package-depending-on-a-pure-cmake-package-using-colcon/) by [Marc Testier](https://answers.ros.org/users/36681/marc-testier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 203 on 2020-02-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Package `foo` is exporting the library target `foo` in the `foo::` namespace.

```
# Export targets.
set(export_targets ${export_targets};${PROJECT_NAME})
export(
  EXPORT export_${PROJECT_NAME}
  FILE "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME}Targets.cmake"
  NAMESPACE ${PROJECT_NAME}::
)
```

But package `bar` is trying to link against exported library target `foo` with no namespace.

```
## Declare a cpp executable
add_executable(Bar src/bar.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(Bar rclcpp)
target_link_libraries(Bar foo)
```

Change it to `foo::foo` to match what package `foo` is exporting

```
target_link_libraries(Bar foo::foo)
```

---

In case you see this again, when debugging CMake packages not finding another package's headers I find it's helpful to use [CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE.html).

```
colcon build --event-handlers console_direct+ --cmake-args -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=TRUE
```

That showed `foo`'s include directory wasn't being passed to the compiler, which suggested I should look at pure CMake issues first.

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Bar.dir/src/bar.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++   -I/tmp/ros2_cmake_test/bar/include -I/opt/ros/eloquent/include  -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=gnu++14 -o CMakeFiles/Bar.dir/src/bar.cpp.o -c /tmp/ros2_cmake_test/bar/src/bar.cpp
```

After fixing the target name, `foo`'s include directory is correctly passed to the compiler and the build succeeds.

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Bar.dir/src/bar.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++   -I/tmp/ros2_cmake_test/bar/include -I/opt/ros/eloquent/include -isystem /tmp/ros2_cmake_test/install/foo/include  -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=gnu++14 -o CMakeFiles/Bar.dir/src/bar.cpp.o -c /tmp/ros2_cmake_test/bar/src/bar.cpp
```

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2020-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marc Testier](https://answers.ros.org/users/36681/marc-testier/) on 2020-02-18**:
It works, thank you for the help!!

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2020-10-29**:
Saved me too. Thanks @sloretz!